# Why is profile detail null in the home component

Tags: angular

I am trying to call profile api if detail is null to avoid api call on every route change every time user comes to home component api should only call if detail is not there and i am using route resolve so that the data gets loaded before the page is shown.

The console.log inside home component results in null while the console.log in auth service prints the correct profile data.

```
export class HomeComponent {
    activeRoute.data.subscribe((data: any)=> {
      this.userDetail = data.profileDetails;
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

App Routing

```
path: '', component: HomeComponent, resolve: { profileDetails: ProfileDetailsResolverService }
```

Auth service

```
 getUserProfile() {
  if(!this.detail) {
    this.http.get(this.userProfileApi).subscribe((res: any)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.detail = res.data;
      return this.detail;
      } else {
      return this.detail;
      }
   });
  }
```

profile resolver service

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      if(localStorage.getItem('access_token')){
      return this.auth.getUserProfile();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is `localStorage.getItem('access_token')` defined in your resolver?

Comment: it just checks if token exists and the token exists when the user is logged in.

Comment: Yeah, but does it return `undefined` or a value? What happens if you comment out the `if`?

Comment: Can you check this method `getUserProfile()`? There is an else part inside subscription without if part..

Answer (score 0):

The `getUserProfile` should not subscribe. The angular route resolver handles this. The `shareReplay(1)` makes sure it does the http call once. The reason you are not getting a value in your component, is because nothing is returned from the `getUserProfile`:

AuthService:

```
userProfile$ = this.http.get(this.userProfileApi).pipe(
  map((res) => res.data),
  shareReplay(1)
);


getUserProfile() {
  return this.userProfile$;
}
```

And change your resolver to:

```
resolve() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('access_token')){
    return this.auth.getUserProfile();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I check here if profile detail already exists dont call the api.

Comment: @zuyi with the `shareReplay(1)`, it will only call it once. If you somehow want to call it again, you should set the `userProfile$` field again